# Docker Elastic Search - How to set vm.max_map_count in windows docker?

Tags: php, docker, elasticsearch, yii2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using elastic search in my php project and having an issue in Windows 10.

> max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase
> to at least [262144]

I fixed it by using this command but I am running it every times before I run **docker-compose up -d**.
I don't want to run it every times. Can anyone tell me the way how I can set vm.max_map_count on windows docker container permanently?

> wsl -d docker-desktop
>
> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Comment: Please share more details. How is this even related to PHP?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I am using elastic search in Yii2/php project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Unfortunately not all `sysctl` options are allowed to be modified at runtime, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime). `vm.`-prefixed sysctls are not namespaced, so that leaves you only the option to modify `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

**Original answer**:

You can tune `sysctl` settings per container in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage
    # https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#sysctls
    sysctls:
      - vm.max_map_count=262144 # won't work, see the update
```

Alternatively you can change this for all containers on the host by adding `vm.max_map_count = 262144` line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Settings in this file are applied on boot.